# .NET and Facebook Integration

Tags: c#, facebook, api

I am creating a website, and I want to integrate Facebook profile with my application users. That is, all the registered users can view facebook profiles of other registered people in my website. Can I do that? Is there any Facebook API available which I can using with .NET code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best libraries available for Facebook and .NET is the Facebook C# SDK.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

There are a couple sample projects for integrating your Facebook app with ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight, and WebForms.

The package is available from NuGet as well.

One of the nice features of this library is it's use of dynamic objects. This article explains the advantages of using dynamic over strongly typed methods.

http://ntotten.com/2010/09/dynamic-objects-and-the-facebook-c-sdk/

Using the Json.NET library, serializing the dynamic responses to POCO is very straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start this is [Face Book Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)