# How to connect facebook with c# to get friends birthdays

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect to facebook and working with api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754124/connect-to-facebook-and-working-with-api)

I have been trying to connect with c# to my facebook account but i don't know how to go by it

Comment: can you be a little more specific? Any sample code? What errors are you getting, or whats not functioning properly?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Facebook SDF for same.
You can find it here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can donwload facebook's development kit for that purpose..The URL is http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: [.NET and Facebook Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835425/net-and-facebook-integration)