# Connect to facebook and working with api

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

Is there any good tutorial how to make simple console facebook appplication which connect to facebook and get list of friends, user photos, status or something. I look at facebook examples of facebook SDK but  if i want to authorize on facebook i must execute FacebookService.ConnectToFacebook method which show login window. But i want show my own login window. Or just store login and password in sql server and time to time get some information about users. Is it real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the tutorial and examples [here](http://fbapi.blogspot.com/p/code-samples.html).

It should have all the functions that you need and is fairly easy to implement.  Trust me, you'll spend hours going elsewhere to figure it out.

As for custom login windows I recommend that you don't do that.  People trust Facebook and don't want to give you their personal info, that's actually a part of your agreement with Facebook.

What you can do however is ask for offline access permission and store the token for future use.  This way if you know who the user is on your end then you can make calls to the API without having to log them into Facebook again.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook requires that users login with them and Facebook will send you back a token which you can use. This is prevent applications "stealing" usernames & passwords, which you could do with your login dialog and also allows users to stop applications in future from accessing their account even if they have logged in previously.

No way round that unfortunately, unless you going to build something that doesn't use the API - for example, a tool which loads a browser in a background, and automates the login as if the user did it. That would lead to pain and suffering though.

Comment: Well...If i know users login and pass can i by hand login at facebook.com and get access to my application?